# Custom default page - edits not saved in content editor web part

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-editor-web-part, web-template

I've created a custom default.aspx page which is provisioned through a custom web template using SharePoint 2010.
I've added the below code to add a content editor web part, with some default content.
When I try to make edits (edit page - stop editing) I see the changes but they are gone again after a reload or refresh of the page.

When I open the page in SharePoint Designer and save it again.
The page works as expected without an issue (edits are visible after reload or refresh).

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="WSCenter1" Title="loc:Content Editor Web Part"><ZoneTemplate>
<WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart runat="server" __MarkupType="xmlmarkup" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{4CF1E63D-4498-4B9D-BD1D-273A9550BFA8}" >
<WebPart xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
  <Title>Content Editor</Title>
  <FrameType>None</FrameType>
  <Description>Allows authors to enter rich text content.</Description>
  <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
  <PartOrder>2</PartOrder>
  <FrameState>Normal</FrameState>
  <Height />
  <Width />
  <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
  <AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange>
  <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
  <AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect>
  <AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>
  <AllowHide>true</AllowHide>
  <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
  <DetailLink />
  <HelpLink />
  <HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode>
  <Dir>Default</Dir>
  <PartImageSmall />
  <MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>
  <PartImageLarge>/_layouts/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge>
  <IsIncludedFilter />
  <ExportControlledProperties>true</ExportControlledProperties>
  <ConnectionID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ConnectionID>
  <ID>g_4cf1e63d_4498_4b9d_bd1d_273a9550bfa8</ID>
  <ContentLink xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" />
  <Content xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor"><![CDATA[<div style="border-bottom: #dbdbdb 1px solid; border-left: #dbdbdb 1px solid; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; width: 740px; padding-right: 10px; height: 200px; border-top: #dbdbdb 1px solid; border-right: #dbdbdb 1px solid; padding-top: 0px"><p style="color: #003365; font-size: 18px; font-weight: normal">
    ​Welcome to this newly created Site!</p>
<p>You can update this content by following the below steps:<br/>1. 
Click on the &#39;Site Actions&#39; button<br/>2. Click on the option &#39;Edit Page&#39;</p></div>
]]></Content>
  <PartStorage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" />
</WebPart>
</WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart>
</ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

Comment: After page refreshing what do you see? Empty content or previous(old) content?

Comment: I see the initial/previous content. E.g. I add more text, I click on stop editing I see my text update but than when I refresh the update is gone and my initial text is shown again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following workaround which suits me.
I removed the above code from mu custom default page and just left a web part zone:

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="Top" Title="loc:Editable Content Top" />
```

To provision the page with my Content Editor I use the below code behind after my new site is created:

```
public static void ProvisionHomePage(SPWeb web) {

                string RootUrl = web.Url;
                SPFile file = web.GetFile(RootUrl + "/" + "default.aspx");

                SPLimitedWebPartManager partManager = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
                ContentEditorWebPart CEpart = new ContentEditorWebPart();

                CEpart.Title = "Welcome Content Editor Part";
                CEpart.ChromeType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeType.None;

                // Create an XmlElement to hold the value of the Content property.
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                XmlElement xmlElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("MyElement");
                xmlElement.InnerText = "<div style=\"border-bottom: #dbdbdb 1px solid; border-left: #dbdbdb 1px solid; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; width: 740px; padding-right: 10px; height: 200px; border-top: #dbdbdb 1px solid; border-right: #dbdbdb 1px solid; padding-top: 0px\"><p style=\"color: #003365; font-size: 18px; font-weight: normal\">​Welcome to this newly created Workspace!</p><p>You can update the content of this box by following the below steps:<br/>1.Click on the &#39;Site Actions&#39; button<br/>2. Click on the option &#39;Edit Page&#39;</p></div>";

                CEpart.Content = xmlElement;
                partManager.AddWebPart(CEpart, "Top", 1);       
        }
```